# How to replace decimal separator dot by decimal separator comma in formattable() package R?

Tags: r, formattable

I have a database and I presented this data using the `formattable()` package. But in my country we use the comma as decimal separator, unlike the standard point used by R.

How could I change it more simply, using the `%>%` operator if possible

```
aa2<-read.table(text="Ano   v   u   a   p   ur  h   e   t
2005    1782135.22  113711.81   98964.84    2207446.25  3876.68 7085.74 3265.89 59030602.87
2006    1719687.83  167937.4    97068.3 2218090.61  3936.55 6811.86 2952.21 59030602.87
2007    1755637.78  122799.6    94299.72    2229590.5   3978.23 6858.66 3171.66 59030602.87
2008    1779051.85  97385.73    101739.73   2225127.88  3996.84 6929.01 2254.58 59030602.87
2009    1805123.7   74061.79    109175.68   2215819.96  4126.57 6771.5  1406.21 59030602.87
2010    1716896.85  168013.92   108014.05   2210652.42  4210.9  7162.69 1535.68 59030602.87
2011    1736892.8   151980.31   113991.8    2200158.22  4259.77 7759.18 1442.06 59030602.87
2012    1757330.63  133273.24   125825.1    2185550.21  4419.45 8129.58 1958.48 59030602.87
2013    1639912.63  248584.77   140183.71   2171799.74  4531.06 8687.48 2777.32 59030602.87
2014    1657021.54  227375.14   180036.19   2136407.51  4631.85 8724.39 2287.94 59030602.87
2015    1720644.41  151089.44   190536.46   2138270.92  4733.71 8911.75 2298.34 59030602.87
2016    1662281.39  202916.33   210776.21   2124964.42  4803.06 8575.97 2165.52 59030602.87
2017    1716427.7   136156.44   230587.13   2117936.68  4809.71 8386.94 2170.25 59030602.87
2018    1638715.79  204483.2    255703.3    2101912.82  4931.96 8366.64 2349.4  59030602.87
", sep="", header = TRUE)


aa2 <- aa2  %>%
   mutate(across(v:t, ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 2, big.mark = "")))

formattable::formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by setting `decimal.mark = ","`:

```
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)

aa2 <- aa2  %>%
  mutate(across(v:t, ~ formattable::comma(., digits = 2, decimal.mark = ",", big.mark = "")))

formattable::formattable(aa2, list(
  'v' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'u' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'a' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'p' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'ur' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'h' = color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc"),
  'e'= color_tile("#00cccc","#0066cc")
))
```

[image]